# User redirecting to login page even after successful authentication in Ez Publish

Tags: symfony, ezpublish, ezplatform

I'm new to Ez publish and symfony. We have a application in Ezpublish where user can login with his username and password.

Even after giving correct credentials it is redirecting to login page.

> We are able to login to the back office with the same credentials. We
>   are facing issue only for end user login to the front office.

Using Ezpublish version 5.4.

Following is my security.yml file

```
security:
providers:
    ezpublish:
        id: ezpublish.security.user_provider

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: []
    ROLE_RISKMANAGER: [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_MANAGER: [ROLE_RISKMANAGER]

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    ezpublish_setup:
        pattern: ^/ezsetup
        security: false

    ezpublish_rest_forgotpassword:
        pattern: ^/api/ezp/v2/user/forgotpassword
        anonymous: ~
        #security: false
        stateless: true

    ezpublish_rest:
        pattern: ^/api/ezp/v2
        stateless: true
        ezpublish_http_basic:
            realm: eZ Publish REST API

    ezpublish_front:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        ezpublish_rest_session: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            require_previous_session: false
            use_forward: false
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /
            use_referer: true
            failure_path: /loginfailed
        logout: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - project.security.device_authenticator

    default:
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    # backend
    - { path: ^/api/ezp/v2/user/forgotpassword,       role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/mot-de-passe-oublie, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/mot-de-passe-oublie, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/creer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/creer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/verification-email, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/verification-email, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/completer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/completer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/mise-a-jour-mot-de-passe, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/mise-a-jour-mot-de-passe, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_fos_user_context_hash, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/activer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/activer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/bo, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/mot-de-passe-oublie, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/creer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/verification-email, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/completer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/mise-a-jour-mot-de-passe, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/_fos_user_context_hash, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/activer-votre-compte, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/country/polygons, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/fr/country/polygons, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/en/country/polygons, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/manage-translation, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/en/country/map, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/en/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: are you getting any server logs when attempting to login?

Comment: No I didn't get any server logs.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD change the default page which is the page where the user is redirected to, if no previous page was stored in the session : 
The value can be a relative/absolute URL or a Symfony route name:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
# ...
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            # ...
            default_target_path: after_login_route_name
```

Source : official symfony 4 documentation 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried in different ways but no luck. You can check my updated security.yml below.
ezpublish_front:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            ezpublish_rest_session: ~
            form_login:
                use_forward: false
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /
                use_referer: true
                failure_path: /loginfailed
            logout: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - project.security.device_authenticator

Comment: `# ezpublish/config/security.yaml
security:
# ...
firewalls:
    dev:
        # ...
    ezpublish_front:
        # ...
        form_login:
            require_previous_session: false
            use_forward: false
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /
            use_referer: true
         guard:
             authenticators:
                 - project.security.device_authenticator
                `

Comment: can you show me the full content security.yml file ?

Comment: I have edited my question with complete security.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I served my domain over HTTPS instead of HTTP then it works.